# Why can't I create the Java list?

Tags: java, maven

I can't make the code below run. The feedback I get is "cannot find symbol" and the place where it occurs is at the letter 'i' on the line "private List products;".

The error message is:  [ERROR] \Users\Filip\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\ProductsCarts\src\main\java\hello\Cart.java:[8,14] error: cannot find symbol

I don't know if it matters but I am using the Spring Boot framework and Maven.

What is wrong? (Observe that the class Cart consist of a list of Product. The code for a product is presented below this on)

```
package main.java.hello;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cart {
    private int id;
    private List<Product> products;

    public Cart(int id){
        this.id=id;
        //products=new LinkedList<Product>();

    }
}
```

The code for Product:

```
package main.java.hello;

public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double priceIncVat;
    private double vatPercentage;
    private double vatAmount;



    public Product(int id, String name, float priceIncVat, float vatAmount){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.priceIncVat=priceIncVat;
        this.vatPercentage=(vatAmount/priceIncVat);

    }

}
```

Here is the complete error message:

```
 [ERROR] \Users\Filip\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\ProductsCarts\src\main\java\hello\Cart.java:[8,14] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project gs-handling-form-submission: Compilation failure
[ERROR] \Users\Filip\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\ProductsCarts\src\main\java\hello\Cart.java:[8,14] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
C:\Users\Filip\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\ProductsCarts>
```

Comment: Is the `Cart` class being used inside a Spring controller? Are you posting the data from a form or maybe using JSON?

Comment: No, I am not even using these two classes. I just created them and wanted to try to run the application before I started to use them. When I run the application in the command prompt it fails and throws the error message.

Comment: Update your question with the occurring error message.

Comment: @FilipEriksson You'll need to provide some more details on what your are trying to do

Comment: The thing is that I had a working spring-root application. For later use I decided to create the classes Cart and Product. They are right now never called. When I try to run the application which worked before it fails and I get the error message that I have know pasted into the question.

Comment: are you sure you have pasted the full error? maybe start with a new project and copy over files one by one?

Comment: Could it be, that your code is compiled with JDK 1.4? That would explain the message, because that version doesn't understand generics.

Comment: Please can you confirm if your Product.java resides at path `\Users\Filip\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspaceCygni\ProductsCarts\src\main\java\hello\Product.java` and what if you use only `List` instead of List of Products, that is, `List<Product>`

Comment: I have now pasted the whole error code in the bottom of my questions. I thought that I had sorted out the important part but maybe I was wrong. I am using jdk 1.8.

Comment: Yes Ajay. That is the path (C: comes before the path you wrote but besides that yes it is correct).Yes it works if I only write "private List products" instead of private List<Product>. Actually I can't even create a Product object. I get the same error message when I write "private Product p;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing directory layouts. Maven puts source code in `src/main/java`, not just `src`. Your package declaration thinks you're just putting the code in `src`. Remove the extra components, and you may not be using m2eclipse to manage the Eclipse build; install and import your project as a Maven project if not.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just put my Product file in the wrong folder. I guess I was looking at the cart class when saying that the path was correct. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the sample java project and install the "m2eclipse" plugin to manage the eclipse build. and then right click on your project go to configure and click on convert to maven option then your project was converted to maven, in you project directory root folder pom.xml file was generated. and check with your package folder like src/main/java and src/test/java etc. then create package in this location src/main/java and create the java file. if u need to add any jar files for your project just update the pom.xml file it contains

```
<groupId>....</groupid>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>....</version>`enter code here`
```